# Count unique values in a column with blanks for each row in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of data (shown below) that I want to count each unique value in this list. I used this formula:
 `SUMPRODUCT((B2:B11540<>"")/COUNTIF(B2:B11540,B2:B11540&""))`

However it gives me the entire count of unique ids and I want to count per row. Also, since this column has lot's of blank fields I am not able to count for each row using `CountIf`. Ideally the blank rows should give `0` and other duplicates should be counted as `1`. Does anyone has a way of solving this?

```
A-2019-000084

A-2019-000141

A-2019-002944

A-2019-000222

A-2019-000222

A-2019-000222

A-2019-000222

A-2019-004606

A-2019-004606


A-2019-000923

A-2019-000699
```

Comment: so what should be the answer with the data you gave?

Comment: So the answer should be each unique element is counted once and blank rows are not counted. For my data the corresponding rows should have 1,1,1,0,0,0,1(A-2019-000222- counting this once),1,0 (this is for that blank after the second A-2019-004606) I need this per row, not the whole total at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use COUNTIF with a variable range:

```
=--AND(A1<>"",COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For a total unique non-blank count of your sample data in column A use,

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A23<>"")/(COUNTIFS(A2:A23,A2:A23,A2:A23,"<>")+NOT(SIGN(LEN(A2:A23)))))
```

For a row-by-row count, (with the first *A-2019-000084* in A2) use this in B2 and drag down.

```
=--(COUNTIFS(A$2:A2, A2, A$2:A2,"<>")=1)
```

Comment: will this simply give me the entire count? I need it per row as mentioned above in my comment